# Реализация Daily Bonus в Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

у меня есть два варианта исхода события if

```
def Entity(message):
time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
timerr = time.localtime().tm_sec
timer = time.localtime().tm_sec
timedelta = timerr - timer
if timedelta == 0 and time_now.hour == time_now.hour:
    id_key = *some ids*
    list_of_randoms = random.sample(id_key, 2)
    first_random_item = list_of_randoms[0]
    second_random_item = list_of_randoms[1]
    markdown1 = '''['''+nickname+'''](tg://user?id='''+str(ids)+''')'''
    markdown2 = '''['''+nickname+'''](tg://user?id='''+str(ids)+''')'''
    bot.send_message(some actions w markdows)
    timerr = timerr + 1
else :
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Time hasn't come yet)
```

Мне нужно, чтобы if исход можно было вызвать только раз в день(не в определенное время, а спустя 24 часа после срабатывания if исхода), а else выполнялось все время до cooldown'а if исхода. В питоне новичек, потому прошу помощи в создании такого таймера(ака кулдаун). Видел что то подобное в хендлерах @commands.cooldown в pydiscord

Comment: ``time_now.hour == time_now.hour`` ???? Какой в этом смысл?

Comment: Изначально я думал добавлять каждый цикл по часу и сравнивать с настоящим временем, и типо 13>12 и условие уже не выполнялось бы, но и это я не придумал как сделать, потому так оно там и осталось